# Laravel how to make new database table from migrate

Tags: php, laravel

[image: here I am doing this]

I am trying to migrate a database table from artisan command.
I have used this command:

```
php artisan migrate --path=/database/migrations/create_registers_table.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd be better off creating all your migrations via artisan.

```
php artisan make:migration create_registers_table
```

This will provide you with the proper naming convention as stated by @jastend.

At that point you simply need to run `php artisan migrate` or `php artisan migrate:refresh`

For more documentation on artisan migrations see [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/migrations)

It's not specified in your question, but if you've upgraded Laravel from an earlier installation to 5.4 or above, then you indeed need to use. The following snippet in your *AppServiceProvider.php*

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;


    public function boot()
    {
      Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
    }
```

Also note there is no `php artisan migrate:fresh` until [5.5LTS](https://laravel-news.com/migrate-fresh)

Comment: Slight typo. `migrate:fresh` is new as of 5.5. `migrate:refresh` has been around a while.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have to follow the file name syntax so that laravel picks it up. Try using:

`YYYY_MM_DD_HHMMSS_create_registers_table.php`

Comment: php artisan migrate --path=/database/migrations/2018_07_15_154230_create_registers_table made this nothing happened. same nothing to migrate. message displays

Comment: Could you check your "migrations" table? Is the respective migration already registered there? If so, delete it and run `php artisan migrate`

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there was something I was missing 
in my AppServiceProvider.php
I wrote this code and now I can  create a new table easily

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
 public function boot()
    {
        Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

the `--path` is only used for folder paths , not file path , so you can do

```
php artisan migrate --path=/database/migrations to run migration from the folder path
```